# Unable to view json file in SQL grid

Tags: sql-server, json, ssms

I am trying to generate json data through sql queries. I used "For Json Auto" to generate json.

One of the table contains html data with html tags. At the time of retrieving it in json it gives me error like :

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Unable to show XML. The following error happened:
Name cannot begin with the '\' character, hexadecimal value 0x5C. Line 1, position 426.

One solution is to increase the number of characters retrieved from the server for XML data. To change this setting, on the Tools menu, click Options.

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

I have already set the XML character limit to unlimited. But still it gives me same error. Any help on this would be thankful.

Comment: Show code, not bold headers.

Comment: And show data that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to get around this was to switch to Results as Text and increase the number of characters per line greatly.